# Instantly closes, no information given

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I run play.bat it doesn't give me any specific errors or any problems it all just closes in a 0.1ms delay

\worldserver.exe"

> Config::LoadFile: Failed open file 'configs/worldserver.conf'

^ if ran in command prompt

I tried running it as administrator, changing the folder location as well as uninstalling and reinstalling it all from scratch